# How do I restore default liveries?

Tags: grid-2

So I have some of the DLC cars from the packs and I tried creating my own liveries using the ingame 'player livery' option.

Now I have the new 'Drift Car' pack, but all the cars are just in their standard 'hero' livery as they are in multiplayer, I'm in single player.

How can I recall the default livery instead of using the player livery? Do I need to store the default first before I make changes? As this happened as soon as the car arrived in my garage I have not had the opportunity to store the default.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I downloaded the drift pack and am now using one of the vehicles in career, single player mode. Except I am not able to select the livery it advertises but only the standard white livery, regardless of whether I'm in 'My Vehicles' or selecting it for a race. Previously I could switch liveries on car select using RB or LB but the '1/3' options no longer appear!

Comment: @JustinMoser As mentioned in the answer this is only available when you are picking a car once the race has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical, that I should find the answer myself as soon as I update the question. It seems that you can use RB + LB (on Xbox controller) to switch the liveries from the car selection screen.

I'm not sure if this is a recent addition or not?

It's worth noting that this option is **only** available if you are selecting a car for a race. It will, currently, not show up in the 'My Vehicles' section.

[image]